# Linux kernel recompilation issue

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-15.04

I successfully recompiled and installed linux `kernel 4.2.0` on my ubuntu 15, I for the learning purposes tried to install another `kernel 4.1.7` on my machine. I followed the exact same procedure to recompile and install it. I become successful to recompile `kernel 4.1.7` but when i installed it and reboot my ubuntu and checked running kernel in it it still shows the 4.2.0 instead of 4.1.7.

what could go wrong in my second installation?

> The process i followed to recompile and install both kernel is

```
 1. downloaded the kernel from kernel.org
 2. made the kernel directory in home and extract kernel.tar.xz there
 3. in terminal go to the kernel directory
 4. run this command sudo apt-get install gcc libncurses5-dev dpkg-dev
 5. make menuconfig
 6. saved the .config file with a different name i-e .config_aa
 7. mv .config_aa .config
 8. make -j 5 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.RIBALINUX deb-dev
 9. sudo make install
 10. sudo reboot
 11. checked kernel version using uname -r
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose kernel for load in bootloader. On Ubuntu it is usually a GRUB2 ([tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)).

This step is missed in some manuals, because one usually intents to build kernel with *newer* version. After installation, the newest kernel version is arranged first, which is loaded by default.

Comment: its mean i hve installed 4.1.7 kernel successfully but to run this i have to use grub 2 and select among kernels at the boot time??

Comment: Yes, kernel is installed successfully, you just need to choose it to load on boot.